# Poison spell and troops running

Tags: clash-of-clans

It would seem with the update clan castle troops move away from the poison spell, unless they are attacking someone in it. Any advice on how to deal with clan castle troops when attacking a base? Just to confirm, does dropping lightening spells and earthquake spells on cc troops do damage to them (including flying ones like dragons)?

On another note, I noticed the poison spell doesn't seem to damage the barbarian king, but does it slow him down?

Answer (score 4):

I'll address lightning and earthquake spells first. Lightning spells will damage all troops that get hit by the individual strikes from the lightning bolts, but it does fairly insignificant damage to high health targets such as dragon, golem, or hound. Earthquake spells on the other hand only damage structures, with some limitation on which structures are affected.

Royalty (barbarian king and archer queen) are affected by the poison spell, however the damage per second dealt to royalty does not increase like it does against clan castle troops, so the amount of damage is rather small.

As for keeping the enemy clan troops inside the poison spell, I recommend taking a few barbarians and dropping them one at a time if they are lower health troops. This does mean you will generally have to lure the cc troops to the side of the base where you can drop the poison and barbs fairly close together. Once the enemy troops are near the edge drop a poison spell on them and drop a barb near the poison spell. Once your barb dies, the enemy troops will start to flee, and you can drop another barb before they leave the radius of the poison spell, making them turn around to attack the barb again. Repeat until clan troops are dead.

If the clan troops are higher health troops like a dragon or golem, I would instead use a few wizards and a poison. Pull the unit to the edge and drop the poison and a few wizards in a semicircle around the poison spell. The Wizards deal high damage and since the unit will have reduced attack speed from poison spell, the Wizards should be able to kill the unit before it kills them.